# Bulid JAXB classes in Gradle usin Kotlin

Tags: gradle, jaxb, kotlin, xjc

Hi I have a task in groovy:

```
task generateJAXBClasses() {
    inputs.dir 'src/main/config'
    outputs.dir 'src/main/java/ad/ecs/struct'
    def jaxbSrcDir = file("${projectDir}/src/main/java")
    doLast {
        ant.taskdef(name: 'xjc', classname: 'ad.ecs.structbuild.XJC2Task', 
                classpath: configurations.generateJAXBClasses.asPath)
        ant.jaxbSrcDir = jaxbSrcDir

        ant.xjc(
            destdir: '${jaxbSrcDir}',
            package: 'ad.ecs.struct',
            schema: 'src/main/config/StructsULink.xsd',
            binding: 'src/main/config/MainBindings.xml',
            readonly: true,
            //header: false,
            argument1: '-Xsetters',
            argument2: '-npa',
        )
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to reference my class `ad.ecs.structbuild.XJC2Task` in Kotlin. I was wondering if there is an alternative to the ant in Kotlin?

Comment: I guess you want to translate that groovy task into kotlin script?

Comment: I recommend you don't put generated sources in `src/main/java`. Keep your directories separate to help with gradle up-to-date checks. Do you commit the generated sources? If yes maybe put in `src/xjc/java`. If no (recommended) maybe put in `$buildDir/xjc` so it's cleaned

Comment: @LanceJava I don't commit generated source. Thank you for the advice, I'll change the location.

Comment: @glee8e So when I convert to kotlin I can still use ant?

Comment: Of course you can. Kotlin, groovy, and others like Clojure, Scala, BeanScript, Jython, JRuby, etc. are all JVM languages and they all have some mechainsm to interop with Java. Since Ant is written in pure Java, it's ok to reference it directly as long as the language specific requirements are meet (there is almost none for kotlin). After all, if a JVM language can't take advantage of existing Java libraries, it should rather be targetting .NET framework, JS, or even native object code directly, not Java.